# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?

Tags: python

This error is referring to "sstax= grosspay*SS_TAX". I don't know what I'm doing wrong. ): After changing the global constants to integers I got another error that said 'TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple' referring to "netpay=(grosspay)-(sstax+fedtax+statetax)".
Here's my code:

```
HOURS_IN_WEEK=40.0
PAY_RATE=16.78
SS_TAX=0.075
FED_INC_TAX=0.014
STATE_LOC_TAX=0.08
UNIONDUES=10.0
HEALTH_INS=35.0

def getInfo():
    hrs=float(input("How many hours did you work this week?: "))
    dependents=float(input("How many dependents do you have?: "))
    if hrs > HOURS_IN_WEEK and dependents >= 3.0:
        overtime=hrs-HOURS_IN_WEEK
        overpay=overtime *(PAY_RATE*1.5)
        pay=(HOURS_IN_WEEK*PAY_RATE)
        grosspay= overpay+pay
        grosspay= grosspay-HEALTH_INS
    else:
        pay = hrs * PAY_RATE
        grosspay = pay
        print grosspay
    return grosspay,hrs,dependents

def tax(grosspay):
    sstax= grosspay*SS_TAX
    fedtax= grosspay*FED_INC_TAX
    statetax=grosspay*STATE_LOC_TAX
    netpay=(grosspay)-(sstax+fedtax+statetax)

    print sstax
    print fedtax
    print statetax
    print grosspay
    print netpay

def main():
    grosspay=getInfo()
    tax(grosspay)

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There error says that you can't multiply a sequence by anything that is not an integer.

You are returning a sequence in the `getInfo()` function:

```
return grosspay,hrs,dependents
```

This is equivalent to:

```
return [grosspay, hrs, dependents]
```

In Python, when you multiply a sequence by an integer, you duplicate the sequence:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Multiplying by a float makes little sense, which is why the error arises.

You can fix it by referencing one specific element of that list (you are after `grosspay`), so change this:

```
def main():
    grosspay=getInfo()
    tax(grosspay)
```

to this:

```
def main():
    grosspay, hrs, dependents = getInfo()
    tax(grosspay)
```

Now `grosspay`, `hrs`, and `dependents` are set and it should work fine.

Comment: `return grosspay,hrs,dependents` returns a tuple, not a list.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really see the difference, but thanks for the catch.

Comment: you'd only notice the difference if you tried to assign to an index later.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `getInfo()` returns a tuple: `grosspay,hrs,dependents` (**remember:** it's the commas that make a tuple, not the parentheses!). This tuple is being assigned to `grosspay` in `main()`, and then  passed to your `tax()` function. In your `tax()` function, you then try to multiply this tuple (which is a kind of sequence) by a float, which Python won't do.

You *can* multiply a sequence by an `int`, which has the effect of repeating the sequence, but this is obviously not what you want to do.

What you need to do is either:

```
grosspay = getInfo()[0]
```

...or...

```
grosspay, _, _ = getInfo()
```

...to extract only the `grosspay` part of the return value from `getInfo()`.